# how to get not duplicated results in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get results from mysql by not letting a specific field gets repeated more than 5 times.

For example, lets say that I have a table like this :

```
-------------
Name        City    
person1     Nashville
person2     Nashville
person3     Nashville
person4     Nashville
person5     Nashville
person6     Nashville
person7     New York
-------------
```

What I want it to return is this :

```
-------------
Name        City    
person1     Nashville
person2     Nashville
person3     Nashville
person4     Nashville
person5     Nashville
person7     New York
-------------
```

where the city field cannot be repeated more than five times! if it was repeated more than fix times, only return the first five results.

This question could be impossible (that is what I am guessing) but if there is a solution or anyway to work around what I am trying to achieve, please tell me! I can use PHP.

Comment: group, having, count... etc :)

Comment: Impossible? It's barely taxing!

Comment: the two comments above me clearly shows that people are too lazy to write a code and explain without making a stupid comment about the question.

Comment: haha..people are also too lazy to do their own research and ask stupid questions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this which uses variables to check the current row to the previous row, if they are the same then the row number will increase if they are not the row number will reset:

```
select name, city
from
(
  select name, 
    city,
    @row:=(case when @prev=city then @row else 0 end) + 1 as rownum,
    @prev:=city pcity
  from yourtable
  order by city, name
) src
where rownum <= 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45501/8)

The result is:

```
|    NAME |      CITY |
-----------------------
| person1 | Nashville |
| person2 | Nashville |
| person3 | Nashville |
| person4 | Nashville |
| person5 | Nashville |
| person7 |  New York |
```

Comment: really good example. I will pick it as the right answer. but I would like to see what others can do.

Comment: @shnisaka you should picks it as the right answer right now, no one comes up with anything better!

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT x.*
      FROM my_table x 
      JOIN my_table y
        ON y.name <= x.name 
       AND y.city = x.city 
     GROUP 
        BY x.city
         , x.name 
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5;
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you allowed to perform more than one MySql command? If so, you can try doing two separate calls --

```
SELECT name, city FROM table WHERE city = 'Nashville' ORDER BY name LIMIT 5;
SELECT name, city FROM table WHERE city <> 'Nashville' ORDER BY name;
```

Someone may need to check on this but the general idea stands. The only problem with this is your end result would not have the table ordered by name. Rather, it'd have the people with the city has 'Nashville' first, and then everyone else.

Comment: I did not downvote you but this requires knowing ahead of time the city names which I doubt will be know at the time of query execution.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. Sorry I completely forgot about that. I am actually kind of a newb to SQL and I'm just trying to get more involved. Thanks for the advice :) and great answer btw.